# Как при каждом внесении в базу данных можно пронумеровывать строки?

Tags: mysql, sql

Прошу помочь мне в написании скрипта для MySQL. Его суть заключается для того чтобы заносить данные пользователей в базу данных, при этом сразу нумеруя строку (в столбце id). Я наблюдал за row_number но так и не понял как он функционирует. Мне кажется что он нумерует все строки по команде за один раз. А мне необходимо, чтобы строки сразу же нумеровались

Comment: где перенумеровывались и зачем?

Comment: Допустим пользователь вводит ФИО - бот их заносит в базу данных. Но! Мне нужно пронумеровывать все строки в бд при помощи ключевого столбца id. ФИО не может быть ключом, ибо оно может повторятся

Comment: [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/example-AUTO_INCREMENT.html) что ли?

Comment: @andreymal вот черт... спасибо, не вспомнил бы даже